# Pip cannot find metadata file - EnvironmentError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, ubuntu-16.04

Whenever I run `pip` to install the Flask packages like `virtualenv` in Ubuntu 16.04, I get this error:

`pip install virtualenv`

`Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (16.1.0)
No metadata found in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv-16.1.0.dist-info/METADATA'`

Here are my pip and python versions:

`pip --version
pip 19.0.1 from /usr/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)`

`python3 --version
Python 3.6.8`

I already tried almost all that I get from the internet to solve this issue like:

`/usr/.local/bin/pip install virtualenv`

But I still get the same error.

I also go into the dist folder to copy the metadata.json with METADATA, but there's no metadata.json file inside.

`cd /usr/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv-16.1.0.dist-info/`

`cp metadata.json METADATA`

`cp: cannot stat 'metadata.json': No such file or directory`

Please help me, I'm stucked with this issue for days. 
Thanks!

Comment: What is the root cause of this problem?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I meet the same problem

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado-6.0.4.dist-info/METADATA
```

then I `cd /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado-6.0.4.dist-info/ && ls`

```
DESCRIPTION.rst  LICENSE.txt  metadata.json
```

finally, I did `cp metadata.json METADATA`
solved the problem.
maybe this is helpful to you.

Answer (score 14):

I encountered the same problem recently.

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.1.dist-info/METADATA'
```

In the folder

```
~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.1.dist-info/
```

I found another one named `pip-19.0.1.dist-info`, and the last one contained all the required files for the `pip`.

I just used

```
cd ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.1.dist-info/
cp -r ./pip-19.0.1.dist-info/* ./
rm -r ./pip-19.0.1.dist-info
```

Obviously that you need to replace `python` version with your own and also check if files

```
entry_points.txt  INSTALLER  LICENSE.txt  METADATA  RECORD  top_level.txt  WHEEL
```

are in here.

Maybe it will help you, luck.

Comment: Thanks! I have held broken packages so after trying that, I just get a new error that says:
`Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv-16.1.0.dist-info/RECORD'` My only option is to just reinstall my Ubuntu for fresh setup. Thanks anyway! This could be a solution for other people.

Answer (score 10):

I just ran into this with a different package, using Python 3.6.5 and pip 19.2.3.  I was hesitant to use the solutions here (and on similar SO questions) so I just tried the following and it cleared up the issue:

`pip install --force-reinstall package_with_metadata_issue`

Note that my case was complaining about the `black` package, which was a dependency of something else I was trying to install (with a simple `pip install other_package`). Black had already been installed and working on my system for a while, so it's unclear how it got into a bad state or what changed in pip such that it couldn't handle the package's state.

To be specific, the OP could try:

`pip install --force-reinstall virtualenv`

Though it seems like many other people here had an issue with pip itself, so that may just be kicking the can down the road until pip is in a good state.

Answer (score 2):

I think the root of your error is that your `pip` is configured to work with Python3.5 (and looks in its specific Pythonpath for the metadata), while your Python version is 3.6.8

Virtual environments in Python 3 have been made simpler, in my opinion, with the usage of the built-in `venv`. Also, your Python and Flask versions should coincide, which is here, not the case.

I'd suggest you take the following steps

- Create a [new virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) using

`python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment`

- Activate the virtual environment by

```
cd /path/to/new/virtual/environment
source env/bin/activate
```

You now have an isolated, clean-slate environment, where you only have a single version of Python.

- Run `pip install --upgrade pip` to upgrade the virtual environment pip to the version that is compatible with your Python version.
- Run `pip install flask`, and install your whole stack from scratch, so that the libraries and Python executable versions are aligned.

Comment: I get this error when executing `python3 -m venv /path/to/my/new/venv`:  
  
`Error: Command '['/usr/path/to/my/new/venv/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

Comment: `/path/to/my/new/venv` should be the path to where you want your virtual environment to be created. It could be like `~/myawesomeproject` or `~/flaskapp`. Where are you trying to create your environment at? Do you have write permissions on that directory?

Comment: Yes, specifically here ~/dashboard. I typed `python3 -m venv ~/dashboard/` Then error returned with `/home/zhanrah/dashboard/venv/bin/python3` above.

Comment: The problem should be that the `venv` version present, is too, incompatible with Python, and stuck with 3.5, as it was also [reported by others](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/1059).
Could you try updating it with `sudo apt-get install python3.6-venv` and reporting back with the result?

Comment: This is what I get when I update it:

`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apache2-bin libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap liblua5.1-0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.`

Comment: `The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3.6-venv
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
Need to get 1705 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1925 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 python3.6-venv amd64 3.6.8-1+xenial1 [1705 kB]
Fetched 1705 kB in 1s (950 kB/s)         
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
 LANGUAGE = (unset),
 LC_ALL = (unset),
 LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",`

Comment: `LANG="en_US.UTF-8" are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Selecting previously unselected package python3.6-venv.
(Reading database . 107252 files and directories currently installed)
Preparing to unpack ./python3.6-venv_3.6.8-1+xenial1_amd64.deb
Unpacking python3.6-venv (3.6.8-1+xenial1)
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1)
Setting up python3.6-venv (3.6.8-1+xenial1)`

Comment: Then I tried to run venv creation again, but I still get the same error.

Comment: The problem gets more and more interesting! Care to check out [this](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/1059#issuecomment-366445592) comment, which has similar issues? You seem to not have set a locale `LC_ALL`, which would not set `venv` correctly.

Comment: Yep, seen that and already tried that but still getting the same error. :( I also tried `sudo apt-get install python3-venv` but I get this error:

`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:`

Comment: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-venv : Depends: python3 (= 3.6.5-3) but it is not installable
                Depends: python3-distutils (>= 3.6.5-2~) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187995/discussion-between-hypertrashpanda-and-zhanrah).

Answer (score 0):

I got same error

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip-18.1.dist-info/RECORD'
```

It seems that there is a conflict between /usr/bin/pip and /home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.7/.

My solution is avoiding the error.

- pip freeze > requirements.txt
- I deleted the /home/user/.local/lib/python3.7 dir
- sudo pip install --upgrade pip
- pip install -r requirements.txt --user
- fixed it

Answer (score 0):

`conda install -c conda-forge requests` solved my problem. Of course, you need to reinstall the package that is problematic for you. Using pip to reinstall it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

do "pip install cython" if you use python or do "pip3 install cython" if you use python3.  I try so many different way and this finally works for me.

Check your actual error message, my error message was
"  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> cytoolz"

Answer (score 0):

try this instead,

```
!pip install cython
```

and

```
!pip install --force-reinstall virtualenv
```

work for me.

I was facing the same problem in in colab

Answer (score 0):

had this problem using google colab. turns out you just need to follow [their instructions](https://automl.github.io/auto-sklearn/master/installation.html#installing-auto-sklearn) and have `apt` install some things beforehand:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential swig python3-dev`

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue and fixed it by creating an empty METADATA file in the .dist-info/ directory using touch

```
    cd /usr/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv-16.1.0.dist-info/
    
    touch METADATA
```