# Pylint installation error "Is a Directory"

Tags: python, pylint

When I try to install PyLint, either from the pop-up in Visual Studio Code that says "Linter Pylint is not installed" or via console using `pip install pylon --user`, I get the following error:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/MyAccountNameHere/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip-19.0.1.dist-info/METADATA'
```

I tried creating a folder named "METADATA" to see if that changed anything, but then it threw this error:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/Users/MyAccountNameHere/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip-19.0.1.dist-info/METADATA'
```

Not sure how to solve, help appreciated.

Comment: this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54552367/pip-cannot-find-metadata-file-environmenterror

Answer (score 0):

**Please try** 
`pip install pylint` (Windows, at an elevated prompt)
`sudo pip3 install pylint` (macOS/Linux)