# Unable to install django-import-export on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: django, ubuntu-18.04

When I try to pip install django-import-export, I get this error:

```
No metadata found in /home/ubuntu/Desktop/dev/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: 
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'/home/ubuntu/Desktop/dev/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlparse-0.3.0.dist-info/METADATA'
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: A possible solution maybe here : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54552367/pip-cannot-find-metadata-file-environmenterror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54552367/pip-cannot-find-metadata-file-environmenterror)

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with:

```
pip3 install --force-reinstall sqlparse
```