# Can't install pip package (No metadata found)

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, anaconda, transformer-model

I'm trying to install [transformers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) with `pip install transformers` inside an [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) environment running [TensorFlow 2.1.0](https://www.tensorflow.org/) and I get the following error:

```
WARNING: No metadata found in c:\users\gamer\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\gamer\\anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow\\lib\\site-packages\\chardet-3.0.4.dist-info\\METADATA'
```

There is a `metadata.json` file in that directory.

It also fails with the same error when installing other packages such as `pip install tf-nightly`.

I have tried enabling long paths as suggested in [Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory \METADATA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54778630/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-errno-2-no-such-file-or).

How do I solve this?

Ps.: installing `transformers` from [anaconda transformers](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/transformers) doesn't work for me, because it's using an old version (I mean, the installation works, but the version doesn't have what I need).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory \\METADATA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54778630/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-errno-2-no-such-file-or)

Comment: Nope... that's the same URL I linked in the question.

Comment: Another one to look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54552367/10682164). I ran into this once with a different package and it seemed like there were a variety of causes and no clear answer that worked for everyone. My solution listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58082184/10682164).

Answer (score 5):

I followed the mentioned directory in error, found a 'metadata.json' file, I made a copy of it without the '.json' extension and it worked.