# docutils ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: pip, docutils

when I run `pip show` I get

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/[my_home] /.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docutils-0.16.dist-info/METADATA'`

and when I try to install `docutils`

`ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/[my_home]/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docutils-0.16.dist-info/METADATA'`

any idea?

thanks

ps: on pip --version 22.0.4 (python 3.8)

Comment: `conda install docutils` did not solve the issue

Comment: Try something from [the search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+No+such+file+or+directory+METADATA). Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62279804/7976758

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so,

also thanks to @phd comment,
I removed all `docutils` folders in `/[my_home]/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/` and things just run fine